# get value of non count id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
/*get value of non count list,using jquery */

<input type="text" id="loc-51-0" value="ahmed">
<input type="text" id="loc-51-0" value="ahmed">
<input type="text" id="loc-51-1" value="mohamed">
<button onclick="save(51)">
<input type="text" id="loc-52-0" value="alaa">
<input type="text" id="loc-52-1" value="karim">     
<button onclick="save(52)">
function save(id){
var x="loc-"+id;
$('input[id^="+x+"]').each(function() {             
         alert( this.value ); // $(this).val();
   });                  
}
```

I need to put variable x into loop but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are having a Syntax Error change this:

```
$('input[id^="+x+"]').each(function() {             
    alert( this.value ); // $(this).val();
});
```

to this:

```
$('input[id^="'+x+'"]').each(function() {             
    alert( this.value ); // $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your value properly:

```
$('[id^="'+ x +'"]').each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Also, because `id` is unique, you just need `[id^=` instead of `input[id^=`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[id^="'+ x +'"]').each(function() {
    alert( this.valule );
}) <- you're missing this `)`
```

also concatenation should be like above.

`$('input[id^="+x+"]')` should be like `$('input[id^="'+ x +'"]')`